# Slim framework, what to use instead of getParsedBody for put method?

Tags: php, rest, api, slim

I'm trying to build a rest API with the slim framework, however I have some trouble with the `put` request which doesn't allow `GetParsedBody`, I looked a lot on internet but didn't find usable method, the only one who worked is `:parse_str($request->getBody()->getContents(), $icone);` where icone is the variable to return.

Here is my code if you want to see it but i don't matter for this question, thank you for your time !

```
$app->put('/{id}', function($request, $response, $args) use ($app){

    $boucle = array();
    $route = $request->getAttribute('route');
    $courseId = $route->getArgument('id');

    parse_str($request->getBody()->getContents(), $icone);

    return $response->withJson($icone);
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achive with getting the content of the body there?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    $route=$req->getParsedBodyParam('route');
    $id=$req->getParsedBodyParam('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
parse_str($request->getBody()->__toString(), $icone);
```

Comment: I managed to succed with changing the html header. Thank you but I want a parsed body and this one return me a full string not parsed that I need to parse myself with regex :/ but thank's for the help ! :)